# How do I find the constant of a continuous joint probability distribution function in R?

Tags: r, self-study, density-function, joint-distribution, continuous-data

I'm wondering how to set up the calculation for a double integral to solve for the value of c for the problem below.

> Consider the joint probability density function $f_{XY} (x, y) = c(x+y)$ over the range $0 < x  < 3$ and $x < y < x + 2$.

I know how to do this for a joint discrete distribution, e.g.

> Consider the joint probability mass function $f_{XY} (x, y) = c(x + y)$ over the nine points with $x = 1, 2, 3$ and $y = 1, 2, 3$.

For this, I'd create two variables so that a function $f_{XY}$ would return all possible values of $x + y$:

```
x = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3))
y = rep(c(1:3),3) 
f_XY = x+y
f_XY
c = 1/sum(f_XY)
```

I'm not sure how to create the variables for x and y when they're continuous, so I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: Why would you do that in R? It's simple algebra. If you want something to do algebra for you R's probably not the right tool. There's various ways to approximate it, but I presume you want an essentially exact answer.

Comment: I'm required to do it in R for this class, unfortunately :/ would be much easier to just do on paper

Comment: What method are they looking for?

Comment: Oh, since this appears to be for a class exercise, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info add the tag and modify the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't think there's any limitation on the method, as long as it works? Sorry, I'm a beginner in R and a little out of practice with stat so I'm not sure if that answers the question. The problem above was the only reference I had for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `integral2` function of the **pracma** package is a possibility:

```
library(pracma)

f <- function(x ,y) x + y

integral2(f, xmin = 0, xmax = 3, ymin = function(x) x, ymax = function(x) x+2)
```

---

If you are not allowed to use a package, you can nest the `integrate` function:

```
inner <- function(x) integrate(function(y) x+y, lower = x, upper = x + 2)$value
integrate(Vectorize(inner), lower = 0, upper = 3)
```

Both methods give `24`, an approximate value of the double integral.

---

Finally, you can use the **SimplicialCubature** package after noticing that the region of integration can be split into two triangles (= simplicies). Moreover, the integrand is a polynomial function, and then **SimplicialCubature** offers the possibility to get the *exact* value of the integral.

```
library(SimplicialCubature)

S1 <- cbind(c(0,0), c(3,3), c(0,2)) # first triangle
S2 <- cbind(c(0,2), c(3,3), c(3,5)) # second triangle
S <- array(c(S1, S2), dim = c(2, 3, 2))

P <- definePoly(coef = c(1,1), k = cbind(c(1,0), c(0,1)))
printPoly(P) # x + y

integrateSimplexPolynomial(P, S)
# 24
```

Comment: Why the downvote ? :-/

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I wasn't aware of the pracma package

Comment: @stat-lilili-894 Glad to help. Please mark my answer as accepted (by clicking the checkmark).